# Netbeans: Can i save Php project outside htdocs folder and still run with localhost?

Tags: windows-explorer, dropbox, localhost, xampp, netbeans

I am using dropbox and i need to save my php project outside htdocs folder, for the files to get synced and to be deployed in heroku. When i do that i get `Object not found!` error. I run it with chrome and it is running through localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i did and worked for me. You can copy the files from your source file in htdocs to another location.

1) Inside Netbeans, hit `control+1` to open the project window
2) Right click on your project name and click **properties**

2) **Tick the first checkbox** saying to *Copy files from Source folder to another location*
3) Right below that there is an option to **Copy to folder**: Choose the location you would like to copy the files to.